# Concancate loop variable with string to produce another variable on the fly

Tags: sass

I am trying make this mixing work.. Any ideas how to concancate a variable name on the fly and make it processed.

```
$colors: purple pink;

@each $color in $colors {

  .box--#{$color} {
    background-color: #{'$ui'}-$color;
  }

}
```

In this case `$ui-red` is a red color variable.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't generate or reference to sass single variables in runtime. But you can store your color codes and names in sass maps (requires sass v3.3) and use it in cycle like this:

```
$colors: ("purple": #f7f,
          "pink":   #ffa);

@each $color-name, $color-code in $colors {
  .box--#{$color-name} {
    background-color: $color-code;
  }
}
```

In CSS you get:

```
.box--purple {
  background-color: #f7f;
}

.box--pink {
  background-color: #ffa;
}
```

Example: http://www.sassmeister.com/gist/c1285109946e5207e441c7ee589dd382